# Find a point at a specific angle from a center point in Go

Tags: go, math, trigonometry

I want to be able to use a center point (x,y) and an angle to find a second point (x2,y2) at a given distance from center.

**For example:**

Center is 0,0

Angle is 50 degrees

Distance is 10

The code below is wrong and trying to interpret this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143932/calculate-point-given-x-y-angle-and-distance however I have no idea how to incorporate the θ using Go.

Sorry I have not done this kind of math for many years and the question may sound stupid.

```
x := math.Cos(50)
y := math.Sin(50)

x2 := x *10
y2 := x *10
```

How do I find x2, y2 using Golang? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post what you have tried and the problems you have. Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, I have already looked at the math answer though having trouble converting that to work in Go.

Answer (score 1):

The Go math functions use *radians*. You may need to convert from *degrees* to *radians* first. See the example below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    x0 := float64(0)
    y0 := float64(0)

    // Assume the positive X axis represents 0 degrees (anti-clockwise direction).
    fmt.Printf("(x0,y0)\tDegrees\tRadians\t(x1,y1)\n")
    for _, degrees := range []float64{0, 30, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315} {
        radians := degrees * math.Pi / 180
        distance := float64(1)
        x1 := x0 + distance*math.Cos(radians)
        y1 := y0 + distance*math.Sin(radians)
        fmt.Printf("(%g, %g)\t%g\t%.3f\t(%.3f, %.3f)\n", x0, y0, degrees, radians, x1, y1)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
(x0,y0) Degrees Radians (x1,y1)
(0, 0)  0       0.000   (1.000, 0.000)
(0, 0)  30      0.524   (0.866, 0.500)
(0, 0)  45      0.785   (0.707, 0.707)
(0, 0)  90      1.571   (0.000, 1.000)
(0, 0)  135     2.356   (-0.707, 0.707)
(0, 0)  180     3.142   (-1.000, 0.000)
(0, 0)  225     3.927   (-0.707, -0.707)
(0, 0)  270     4.712   (-0.000, -1.000)
(0, 0)  315     5.498   (0.707, -0.707)
```

Comment: Thanks will give this a try today or tomorrow and let you know if I can get it to work. Appreciate the response.